# Can someone explain why the answer to $\int \frac{x^2}{2 + \tan x}\, dx$ is in terms of logs and complex numbers?

Tags: integration

This is what Wolfram calculator gives:

$$\int \frac{x^2}{2+\tan x} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{30} \left[6 i x \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(-\frac{3}{5} - \frac{4i}{5}\right) e^{-2 i x}\right) + 3 \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\left(-\frac{3}{5} - \frac{4i}{5}\right) e^{-2 i x}\right) + (4 + 2 i) x^3 + 6 x^2 \log\left(1+\left(\frac{3}{5} + \frac{4i}{5}\right) e^{-2 i x}\right)\right] + c$$
(assuming a complex-valued logarithm)

So now I have an answer in terms of complex numbers and LaTex, how would I show that say pi^3 /(81(2 + sqrt(3))) was greater than or less than this answer?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the formula is quite complicated, so you might want to write it with Latex

Comment: Have you tried to differentiate the output? If so, where did you get stuck? If not, it is a suggestion to do so.

Comment: In the title, you ask to confirm the answer, but at the end of the text, you have another question.

Comment: It is probably expanding $\tan(x)$ as the complex exponential and then breaking it up into multiple terms

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{x^2}{\tan\left(x\right)+2}=\dfrac{x^2}{2-i\frac{ e^{i x}-e^{-i x}}{e^{i x}+e^{-i x}}}$$

Now, the nightmare starts !